# Bdd scenarios for web application that needs to log in

Tags: bdd, specflow, gherkin

So I know for behavior driven testing a known rule is to make sure the scenarios are not dependent on eachother, that sounds good and makes sense, but I don't understand how it's supposed to work for an web application you need to sign into.
Currently I have a method that sets up the driver before every single scenario using backgroud, which also logs in the user, which is fine. However, when I get hundreds of tests and 95%+ of them are going to be testing features after logging in, do I really need to log in separately for every single one of those scenarios? It just doesn't seem very efficient?

Here is an example, just imagine I have 100 more of these similar scenarios testing very simple features, but requires the user to be logged in:

```
Feature: Chat Functions

Background:
Given user is logged in

@tag
Scenario: MuteButton
    Given user is in a active chat
    When the mute button is pressed
    Then they will not receive any notifications from this chat

@tag
Scenario: FavoriteButton
    Given user is in a active chat
    When the favorite button is pressed
    Then the chat will appear under the user's favorite list
```

Ideally I'd just want it to log in first, and then run the hundreds of scenarios that requires the login, but from what I have read online on the topic it seems like that is a bad way to go about it? What is the right way to do deal with a situation like this? Because alot of the time the scenarios themselves could take as little as 1 or 2 seconds to run, but logging in takes like 10, which will drastically slow down the entire suite's run time.

Comment: How does logging in take 10 seconds? Wow. An automated bot should be able to whip through that quicker than 10 seconds, unless you've got MFA to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle logging the user in with a before feature hook. That would reduce logins to once per feature file. I would caution against logging in just once, because future scenarios or features might need different users with different permissions.

Another downside is that if the browser crashes you don't want every test after that to fail. In my experience opening a new browser window and logging in for each scenario gave me the most stable builds, and limited the effects of Selenium crashing.

To be honest I would just keep the `Given user is logged in` step in the background. You mentioned that logging in takes 10 seconds, which seems like a long time to me. I would make sure the slowdown isn't related to putting data in the system or the time it takes for the browser to open up. You don't want to re-engineer a large part of your test code only to find out you haven't fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Besides a Login screen, you may have a need to 'bypass' other screens such as Welcome, Set Your Details, Add Your First Appointment (all dependant on the application under test).

The UI flow may contain unavoidable steps. However, what you will find is that these steps can most likely be replicated with API calls.

You could have a step that is User Enters Their Details and you have to do it for every new user. You can create a User Enters Their Details http version in the tests that are not focused on testing the User Details.

For login you can also get and save cookies for faster login.